# About This Mac > Storage shows 10GB Backups, but Time Machine is Disabled

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine, disk-utility, storage

I'm trying to figure out what's going on with my storage.
`About This Mac > Storage` shows that there's ~11GB of Backups.
Disk Utility seems to sort the same files as "Other".

Googling tells me that the backups shown in `About This Mac > Storage` are part of Time Machine (and that they will be automagically deleted if the space is needed), **BUT** Time Machine is disabled, and has never been used (and there are no `/.MobileBackups` or `/Volumes/MobileBackups` folders).

Running Disk Utility's 'First Aid' from the Recovery Partition says there's nothing wrong with the disk.

Also, Disk Utility reports two different sizes for "available" (in the same window). The difference seems to be the size of the supposed backups.

[image: Screenshot of Disk Utility, About This Mac & Time Machine]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "backups" no longer show up. Afaik I did not do anything.